# How to Convert from Stream of PNG image data to Emgu.cv Mat variable in c#?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I Want to convert stream complete slowly contains PNG data to Mat from Emgu.cv and show it in a picturebox with c# language.

This is the function i used to convert 2d array into mat:

```
 private Emgu.CV.Mat createImage16Bit(double[,] data, int width, 
 int height, string path)
 {
 const int bytesPerPixel = 2;
 WICImagingFactory wic = new WICImagingFactory();
 IWICBitmapEncoder encoder = 
 wic.CreateEncoder(ContainerFormat.Png);
 FileStream stream = File.Create(path);
 encoder.Initialize(stream, 
 WICBitmapEncoderCacheOption.WICBitmapEncoderNoCache);
 IWICBitmapFrameEncode frame = encoder.CreateNewFrame(out 
 IPropertyBag2 options);
 frame.Initialize(options);
 frame.SetPixelFormat(WICPixelFormat.WICPixelFormat16bppGray);
 frame.SetSize(width, height);
 byte[] imageData = new byte[width * height * bytesPerPixel];
 double[,] img = new double[width, height];
 int z = 0;
 try
 {

     for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
     {
         for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
         {
             int index = (y * width + x) * 2;


             double high_band = 65535;
             double low_band = 0;
             img[x, y] = data[x, y];
             if (img[x, y] > high_band)
             {
                 img[x, y] = high_band;
             }
             else if (img[x, y] < low_band)
             {
                 img[x, y] = low_band;
             }

             ushort number = Convert.ToUInt16(img[x, y]);
             byte lowerByte = (byte)(number & 0xFF);
             byte upperByte = (byte)((number >> 8) & 0xFF);

             imageData[index] = lowerByte;
             imageData[index + 1] = upperByte;

             z++;
         }
     }
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {

 }

 IWICBitmapFrameEncodeExtensions.WritePixels(frame, height, width * bytesPerPixel, imageData);
 frame.Commit();
 encoder.Commit();
 stream.Dispose();
 Emgu.CV.Mat mat = new Emgu.CV.Mat(path, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.Unchanged);
 return mat;
}
```

And use this function like this:

```
Emgu.CV.Mat output = createImage16Bit(doubleArray, 768, 512, @"output_mat.png");
```

I converted stream into a double array with WICdotnet library and use filestream and it worked. but i dont want to use files in this process!

Comment: If you show us the code you’re using, it may be possible to find a solution

Comment: I added my code.